Deleting a picture on telegram
If I deleted pictures from telegram but also selected the option to also have the pictures deleted from the recipient is there a possibility they could still have it, as it said delete and select delete for recipient? Could they have saved it and i was still able to select that option when delecting it


Could they have saved it and I was still able to select that option
when deleting it

Yes, "deleted from the recipient" should be interpreted as "remove from the recipient's Telegram app the next time it is connected."  This has no bearing on anything they did with the image outside of the app.
You are only deleting it from sync'ed versions of the app.

If they saved the image locally that copy would never be deleted.
If any of their app instances hasn't sync'ed with Telegram's servers, the cached copy would not yet be deleted.
If any device used to access Telegram was backed up while the image was available, the image could also be in that backup.

